# No route to host/WinError 10060 when connecting to Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian

When trying to connect clients to Raspberry Pi server, Linux returns "No route to host" error, and Windows 10 returns "WinError 10060".

**server.py** - ran on Raspberry Pi 2 (rasbian, Bullseye, kernel 6.1.21-v7+)

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("192.168.0.17", 1234))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")
    clientsocket.send(bytes("Welcome to the server!", "utf-8"))
```

**client.py** - ran on Linux and Windows 10

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.0.17", 1234))

msg = s.recv(64)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

I have already tried:

- ifconfig confirmed Ras-Pi ipv4 was 192.168.0.17 as expected.
- Checked if port 1234 was available on all devices. It is.
- Pinging the ras-pi from the Linux and Windows 10 devices returned 0% packet loss.
- Disabled Firewalls on all devices, just to be sure.
- Ras-Pi client.py and Linux client.py connect to Windows server.py.
- Neither Linux client.py nor Windows client.py connect to Ras-Pi server.py.
- Connecting Ras-Pi to network via wifi and then ethernet.
- "nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24" to check if 192.168.0.17 was there and it didn't show up, even though ping works.
- Installed outstanding Ras-Pi updates, then rebooted.
- Enable SSH on Ras-Pi, then tried connecting from Linux and failed with same error (No route to host).
- Turned the router off and on again.

Non of these resulted in a solution to the Ras-Pi not being found by other devices on the network.

There were a few other things that I tried, such as adding firewall rules, but later reset to default before disabling the firewall all together.

The only thing left that I can think of to try is to completely reload the OS on the Ras-Pi, but would rather not if I can avoid it.

The thing most puzzling is that I can ping the Ras-Pi, but any other form of connection returns an error you would expect if the ip didn't exist. But it does. I hope.

I fear there's a simple solution that I've overlooked. What test have I forgotten?

Comment: Just another idea (but I doubt that it helps, actually) : Replace the `bind` call in the server by `s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 1234))`

Comment: @MichaelButscher It worked! Thank you! Spent the best part of a day on this. Could you repost that comment as a solution so I can mark it as the answer? Not sure why it worked though, any guesses?

The only thing I did in between time was to reload the OS, but the problem was still there until I tried your suggestion. Thanks again

Comment: I made an answer. I don't know any more detail than that about why it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the server uses another network adapter for the connection to the client.

Replacing

```
s.bind(("192.168.0.17", 1234))
```

by

```
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 1234))
```

in the server code makes the server listen on all of its adapters on port 1234.